# React native Base - Sidebar opens underneath the screen

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm two days trying to make a sidebar work using react native base.

I'm using the example I saw on the react native base website (https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Drawer)

The sidebar is running (it opens). But there's been a kind of modal over the sidebar. The sidebar does not turn white. It gets dark as if it's underneath where it should be.

Look at the two pictures

[image]

[image]

I do not know what to do. Does anyone have an idea how to make this sidebar menu work? Here's the code I'm using

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { Header, Left, Button, Icon, Right, Body, Title, Drawer } from 'native-base'
import SideBar from './src/components/SideBar'

export default class AppHeader extends Component {
  closeDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  }
  openDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
       ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
      >
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.openDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Title</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name="bulb" />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
module.exports = AppHeader
```

SideBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

import {Content} from 'native-base';

export default class SideBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Content style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'}}>
            <Text>Side Bar</Text>
          </Content>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = SideBar;
```

Answer (score 2):

try to insert the **Container** Tag inside Sidebar.class:

```
export default class SideBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
          <Content style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'}}>
            <Text>Side Bar</Text>
          </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

alternatively you can try to follow (as I did) the structure of NativeBaseKitchenSink: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink